# How to Configure Spring Oauth2 for Multi tenant

Tags: java, spring, oauth, multi-tenant

I'm currently developing multi-tenant application using spring and using oauth. Every tenant will have different database. If my url is tenant1.xxx.com, then it will use tenant1 database, etc.

My request already successfully routed using AbstractRoutingDataSource but not the authentication. So when I ask an access token, it still using the default datasource. I think my problem is in oauth2 configuration that set datasource like TokenStore, etc.

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
}
```

Is there anyway that token store can choose datasource according to current tenant?

Comment: you wanna choose datasource or you wanna save multi tenant in the same database?

Comment: I want to choose datasource. So every tenant will use different database for oauth

Comment: same is my question, did you find any answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to give solutions

1) If you check to code inside the JdbcTokenStore then we will find that it's using inside the JdbcTempaltes so JPA or Hibernate routing will not work for that in that case a part of the solution you have to implements org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore with JPA implementation.

2) If you do not like to do a solution No 1 then you can also implement AbstractRoutingDataSource and while creating TokenStore passed the routing data source.